Telethon Entity With Linux and Google Cloud
I have a message forwarding bot on Telegram that works perfectly in Python on Windows.
When I try to run the same code in a VM on Google Cloud, because it is Linux, it keeps giving me an entity error.
I confess that I couldn't solve it. can you help me? Below I will put my code, and if you can, what would the corrected code look like?
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events
from time import sleep
import requests
from password import api_hash,api_id

sessao = 'Forward Message'

def main():
        print ('Monitoriamento iniciado...')
        client = TelegramClient (sessao, api_id, api_hash)
        @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats = [1234567899876]))
        async def enviar_mensagem(event):
            await client.send_message(987654321123,event.raw_text)
        client.start()
        client.run_until_disconnected()
main()

The error message appears when trying to forward the message:

Unhandled exception on enviar_mensagem Traceback (most recent call
last):   File
"/home/nnovais_nivaldo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telethon/client/updates.py",
line 570, in _dispatch_update
await callback(event)   File "/home/nnovais_nivaldo/boot_repasse/Forward Message.py", line 19, in
enviar_mensagem
await client.send_message(987654321123,event.raw_text)   File "/home/nnovais_nivaldo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telethon/client/messages.py",
line 840, in send_message
entity = await self.get_input_entity(entity)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/nnovais_nivaldo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py",
line 468, in get_input_entity
raise ValueError( ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerUser(user_id=987654321123) (PeerUser). Please read
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html to find out
more details.

I tried to understand the telethon documentation, I tried chatgpt, I searched in several places and nothing.

known entities are stored in a .session file. and your "Linux" aka the other system doesn't have the same file. Also you must pass -100 for supergroups and channels, server has special exception for chats you have joined and won't need them be in the session, now the 1234567899876 is considered of a user id. so prepend -100 to it: -1001234567899876
